# Soundcloud API "Request was not processed"

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm seeing a new error via the [Soundcloud API](https://developer.soundcloud.com/).  It is intermittent, so it may be backend+bug related or it could be a sign of further reduced access to the Soundcloud API.

A [User](https://developer.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) request now returns the following:

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/cadenzamusic?client_id=CLIENT_ID
(replace CLIENT ID with your own)

An HTTP/1.0 200 OK response is returned, but I'm getting the following string, rather than the User JSON object as expected:

> Request was not processed by the server due to an error and is safe to retry

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I just started seeing this too, worst part is the error isn't JSON so my app crashes. SoundCloud just posted a notice that they are experiencing issues. I hope the resolve it soon and maybe implement a better mechanism for sending us errors in the future. http://status.soundcloud.com/post/150446721145/playback-issues#note-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated earlier this was an error on SoundClouds part. Their servers were experiencing issues and it seems that they have resolved since **17:26 CET/ 08:26 PST**

If you want more information on the status check out their post [here](http://status.soundcloud.com/post/150446721145/playback-issues#note-container).
When experiencing similar issues in the future it might prove useful to check the [SoundCloud status page](http://status.soundcloud.com) to see if they are aware of any issues.